# removing data based on multiple date columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe which includes the following variables: `covid alert date`, `vax dose 1` to `vax dose 5` (these are vaccine brands), `date dose 1` to `date dose 5` (these are the vaccination dates).

The dataset includes all covid vaccines they have ever received however I really only want to keep the vaccine brands and dates that fall before their `covid alert date`. Is there a way to look at the `covid alert date` for each row and only keep the vaccine brands and dates that fall before that date? Anything after that date can be changed to NA.

```
sample_data <- tibble(`covid alert date` = as.Date(c('2022-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01','2022-05-01','2022-06-01','2022-07-01','2022-08-01','2022-09-01','2022-10-01')),             
                     `vax dose 1` = c("Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca"), 
                     `date dose 1` = as.Date(c('2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2023-04-01','2023-05-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-08-01','2023-09-01','2023-10-01')),
                     `vax dose 2` = c("Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     `date dose 2` = as.Date(c('2021-04-01','2021-03-01','2021-05-01','2023-06-01','2023-07-01', '2021-08-01', NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                     `vax dose 3` = c("Pfizer", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     `date dose 3` = as.Date(c('2022-04-01','2021-12-01','2021-12-01','2023-12-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                     `vax dose 4` = c("Pfizer", "Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     `date dose 4` = as.Date(c('2022-12-01','2022-12-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                     `vax dose 5` = c("Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     `date dose 5` = as.Date(c('2023-11-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)))
```

I am very new to using R so any assistance is greatly appreciated. I have included some sample data above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With this approach you first make all dates `NA` that are after `covid alert date`, and when `date dose X` is `NA`, you then make the corresponding `vax dose X` `NA` as well

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_data |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), \(x) as.Date(if_else(x < `covid alert date`, x, NA))),
         across(starts_with("vax"), \(x) if_else(is.na(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "vax", "date"))), NA, x)))

   `covid alert date` `vax dose 1` `date dose 1` `vax dose 2` `date dose 2` `vax dose 3` `date dose 3` `vax dose 4` `date dose 4` `vax dose 5` `date dose 5`
   <date>             <chr>        <date>        <chr>        <date>        <chr>        <date>        <chr>        <date>        <chr>        <date>       
 1 2022-01-01         Astrazeneca  2021-01-01    Astrazeneca  2021-04-01    NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 2 2022-02-01         Moderna      2021-02-01    Moderna      2021-03-01    Moderna      2021-12-01    NA           NA            NA           NA           
 3 2022-03-01         Pfizer       2021-03-01    Pfizer       2021-05-01    Pfizer       2021-12-01    NA           NA            NA           NA           
 4 2022-04-01         NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 5 2022-05-01         NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 6 2022-06-01         Pfizer       2021-06-01    Pfizer       2021-08-01    NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 7 2022-07-01         Astrazeneca  2021-07-01    NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 8 2022-08-01         Moderna      2021-08-01    NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
 9 2022-09-01         NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA           
10 2022-10-01         NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA            NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

> The dataset includes all covid vaccines they have ever received however I really only want to keep the vaccine brands and dates that fall **before** their 'covid alert date'.

If base R is an option and `reshape` not on your list of favorite functions, here a dubious approach based on the principle `split`-(l)`apply`-combine.

```r
cp = \(v1, v2, operator) { s = getFunction(operator)(v1, v2); s[is.na(s)] = FALSE; s }
cbind(xyzzy[1L], 
      lapply(split.default(xyzzy[-1L], gl(ncol(xyzzy[-1L]) / 2L, 2L)), 
             \(x) { x[cp(x[grep("date", colnames(x))], xyzzy[1L], ">"), ] = NA; x }) |> 
        do.call(what = cbind))
```

gives

```r
   covid.alert.date 1.vax.dose.1 1.date.dose.1 2.vax.dose.2
1        2022-01-01  Astrazeneca    2021-01-01  Astrazeneca
2        2022-02-01      Moderna    2021-02-01      Moderna
3        2022-03-01       Pfizer    2021-03-01       Pfizer
4        2022-04-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
5        2022-05-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
6        2022-06-01       Pfizer    2021-06-01       Pfizer
7        2022-07-01  Astrazeneca    2021-07-01         <NA>
8        2022-08-01      Moderna    2021-08-01         <NA>
9        2022-09-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
10       2022-10-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
   2.date.dose.2 3.vax.dose.3 3.date.dose.3 4.vax.dose.4 4.date.dose.4
1     2021-04-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
2     2021-03-01      Moderna    2021-12-01         <NA>          <NA>
3     2021-05-01       Pfizer    2021-12-01         <NA>          <NA>
4           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
5           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
6     2021-08-01         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
7           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
8           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
9           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
10          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
   5.vax.dose.5 5.date.dose.5
1          <NA>          <NA>
2          <NA>          <NA>
3          <NA>          <NA>
4          <NA>          <NA>
5          <NA>          <NA>
6          <NA>          <NA>
7          <NA>          <NA>
8          <NA>          <NA>
9          <NA>          <NA>
10         <NA>          <NA>
```

---

Data:

```r
xyzzy = data.frame(`covid alert date` = as.Date(c('2022-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01','2022-05-01','2022-06-01','2022-07-01','2022-08-01','2022-09-01','2022-10-01')),             
                              `vax dose 1` = c("Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca"), 
                              `date dose 1` = as.Date(c('2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2023-04-01','2023-05-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-08-01','2023-09-01','2023-10-01')),
                              `vax dose 2` = c("Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Astrazeneca", "Moderna", "Pfizer", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                              `date dose 2` = as.Date(c('2021-04-01','2021-03-01','2021-05-01','2023-06-01','2023-07-01', '2021-08-01', NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                              `vax dose 3` = c("Pfizer", "Moderna", "Pfizer", "Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                              `date dose 3` = as.Date(c('2022-04-01','2021-12-01','2021-12-01','2023-12-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                              `vax dose 4` = c("Pfizer", "Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                              `date dose 4` = as.Date(c('2022-12-01','2022-12-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                              `vax dose 5` = c("Moderna", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                              `date dose 5` = as.Date(c('2023-11-01', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)))
```